# Comment the same again and again

Tags: php, html, comments

I am trying to make a comments section, where people can comment stuff on my webpage.
All the comments get to a database. Alle that works fine.
The only problem I have is, when i have commented some stuff and reload the webpage it comment the same thing again.

Is there a if statement or something to prevent this?

```
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<div style="border-style: solid; border-color: #808080; border-width: thin">
            <div style="width: 1%"><p style="font-size: 10px; margin: 0px">'.$info['Navn'].'</p></div>
            <p>'.$info['Besked'].'</p>
    </div>';
}
 if (isset($_POST['navn']) && isset($_POST['besked']) && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $navn2 = $_POST['navn'];
    $besked2 = $_POST['besked'];

    $data = "INSERT INTO `tester`.`davs` (`Navn`, `Besked`) VALUES ('$navn2', '$besked2');";
    $resultalt = mysql_query($data);
    if ($resultalt) {
            echo "$resultat";
    }else{
            echo "$resultat";
    }
    mysql_close();
}
?>

<form action="database.php" method="post" id="commentform">

    <label for="comment_author" class="required">Your name</label>
    <input type="text" name="navn" id="comment_author" value="" tabindex="1" required="required">

    <label for="comment" class="required">Your message</label>
    <textarea name="besked" id="comment" rows="10" tabindex="4"  required="required"></textarea>

    <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="1" id="comment_post_ID" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit comment" />

</form>
```

my php code:
http://pastebin.com/bQ7c1MPD
my inputs:
http://pastebin.com/P9uc6Hhz

Comment: You're likely posting the data twice if the page is refreshed... why don't you paste what code you have in your actual question rather than directing us to another site?

Answer (score 0):

Use tokens in your HTML form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$_SESSION['token'] = uniqid(); ?>" />
```

This require this at the top of the PHP script (before any output):

```
session_start();
```

For validation:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']))
```

Full code: [PHP](http://pastebin.com/TePNJyGH) | [Form](http://pastebin.com/33zfaYsz)